# PreferenceFragment inflated onto CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview, preferencefragment

I'm having difficulty getting the layout_height right inflating a PreferenceFragment onto a CardView.

Everything works well, including the NestedScrollView to collapse my Toolbar, but for some reason my Preferences are only filling the first position of the list. It's scrollable, but it needs to fill the entire Card.

Any ideas on what might be going on here?

Edit: It's definitely the NestedScrollView causing the problem. Now if only I can find a workaround..

I might also not fully understand Cards, since other Layouts, I can't seem to get them to entirely fill the View, minus that little bit of margin.

Here's my PreferenceFragment XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:elevation="100dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_initial_background"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/scrollview_padding_default" >

    <LinearLayout

        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <ListView

            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="0dip"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/preference_fragment_padding_bottom"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/preference_fragment_padding_side"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/preference_fragment_padding_side"
            android:scrollbarStyle="@integer/preference_fragment_scrollbarStyle"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" />

        <TextView

            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/preference_fragment_padding_side"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <RelativeLayout

            android:id="@+id/button_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <Button

                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/back_button_label"/>

            <LinearLayout

                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                <Button

                    android:id="@+id/skip_button"
                    android:layout_width="150dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dip"
                    android:text="@string/skip_button_label"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                <Button

                    android:id="@+id/next_button"
                    android:layout_width="150dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dip"
                    android:text="@string/next_button_label"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And my PreferenceFragment Java, where the inflation happens:

```
package app.my.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import app.my.sample.R;

public class SettingsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

private int mPage;

public static SettingsPreferenceFragment newInstance(int page) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    SettingsPreferenceFragment fragment = new SettingsPreferenceFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater paramLayoutInflater, ViewGroup paramViewGroup, Bundle paramBundle) {

    return paramLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preference_list, paramViewGroup , false);

    //return super.onCreateView(paramLayoutInflater, paramViewGroup, paramBundle);

}

}
```

Comment: android:elevation="100dp" ooha :D

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question but maybe someone will find this answer useful.
Try Adding attribute `android:fillViewport="true"` to `NestedScrollView`.